# Determine distribution of a limit of random variables

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, convergence, moments

> Suppose a box contains a blue ball and green ball. After every hour a ball is chosen from the box randomly and then is put back with another ball of the same colour.
>
> After $h$ hours, there are $h + 2$ balls:
>
> Let $B_h + 1$ denote the number of of blue balls out of the $h + 2$, and define $P_h := \frac{B_h + 1}{h + 2}$.
>
> It can be shown that
>
> 1. $\{P_h\}_{h \ge 1}$ is a martingale relative to the filtration $\{\sigma(B_1, ..., B_h)\}_{h \ge 1}$
> 2. $P(B_h = j) = \frac{1}{h+1}$ for $j = 0, 1, ..., h$
> 3. $\lim P_h$ exists. Denote it as $B$
>      (It would be $P$ but see previous revision...)
>
> **Determine the distribution of $B$.**

---

I have two solutions, each of which attempts to compute the moment generating function of $B$, which I hope exists.

One is Uniform while the other is Bernoulli.

---

1.

$$M_{B}(t) = E[\exp(tB)]$$

$$= E[\exp(t\lim \frac{B_h + 1}{h+2})]$$

$$= E[\lim\exp(t \frac{B_h + 1}{h+2})]$$

$$= \lim E[\exp(t \frac{B_h+ 1}{h+2})]$$

by some convergence theorem I hope?

$$= \lim \frac{1}{h+1}[\exp(t \frac{1}{h+2}) + \exp(t \frac{2}{h+2}) + ... + \exp(t \frac{h+1}{h+2})]$$

Case 1: $t \ne 0$

$$= \lim \frac{a(h)}{(h+1)(1-a(h))} (1-a(h)^{h+1}), \ \text{where} \ a(h) := e^{\frac{t}{h+2}}$$

$$= \lim \frac{a(h)}{(h+1)(1-a(h))} \lim (1-a(h)^{h+1})$$

$$= \lim \frac{a(h)}{(h+1)(1-a(h))} (1-e^t)$$

$$= \frac{1-e^t}{-t}$$

$$= \frac{e^t-1}{t}$$

Case 2: $t = 0$

$$= \lim \frac{1}{h+1}[\exp((0) \frac{1}{h+2}) + \exp((0) \frac{2}{h+2}) + ... + \exp((0) \frac{h+1}{h+2})]$$

$$= \lim \frac{1}{h+1} (1)(h+1) = 1$$

Thus, $M_B(t) = \frac{e^t-1}{t} 1_{t \ne 0} + 1_{t = 0}$

This is the mgf of $Unif(0,1)$

---

2.

$$M_{B}(t) = E[\exp(tB)]$$

$$= E[\exp(t\lim \frac{B_h + 1}{h+2})]$$

$$= E[\exp(t\lim \frac{B_{h+1} - B_h}{1})]$$

by Stolz–Cesàro theorem

$$= E[\exp(t\lim (B_{h+1} - B_h))]$$

$$= E[\lim \exp(t (B_{h+1} - B_h))]$$

$$= \lim E[\exp(t (B_{h+1} - B_h))]$$

by some convergence theorem I hope?

Computing $E[\exp(t (B_{h+1} - B_h))]$ gives:

$$E[\exp(t (B_{h+1} - B_h))]$$

$$= E[E[\exp(t (B_{h+1} - B_h)) | B_h]]$$

$$= E[e^{t (0)}(1 - P_h) + e^{t (1)} P_h]$$

$$= E[(1 - P_h) + e^{t} P_h]$$

$$= E[(1 - P_h) + e^{t} P_h]$$

$$= E[(1 - P_h)] + E[e^{t} P_h]$$

$$= (1 - E[P_h]) + e^{t}E[P_h]$$

$$= (1 - (\frac 1 2)) + e^{t}(\frac 1 2)$$

$$= (\frac 1 2) + e^{t}(\frac 1 2) = (1 + e^{t})(\frac 1 2)$$

Hence, $M_{B}(t) = \lim (1 + e^{t})(\frac 1 2) = (1 + e^{t})(\frac 1 2)$.

This is the mgf of $Bernoulli(1/2)$.

---

Any correct? If so which, and why is the other wrong? If both wrong, how can I approach this problem?

Comment: Exactly what kind of "limit" does (3) refer to?  Pointwise, the distribution function of $B_h$ obviously goes to zero everywhere by virtue of the result in (2).

Comment: @whuber It's not limit in distribution. It's the limit in...almost sure convergence or something like that. The one that exists if sequence us a nonnegative martingale

Comment: @whuber btw maybe the PDF doesn't exist but the distribution exists...?

Comment: The distribution function to which I referred is the *CDF*, not the PDF.  The limit *does* exist--but it's not a distribution function: it's identically zero. Are you sure the third question isn't asking about $P_h$ instead of $B_h$? If you're not sure what kind of limit you're finding, you can't do much at all to solve the problem, so you should first find that out.

Comment: @whuber HAHAHA THANKS. It's supposed to be Ph not Bh

Comment: I think you've made this *way* too complicated.  Look at the distribution function for arbitrary $t \in (0, 1)$ and take a limit.  It should be fairly intuitive that a discrete uniform distribution over the unit interval would converge to a continuous analog.  More difficult is to find the distribution when we don't start with two balls of different colors.  This problem (the Polya urn model) is well-studied and you can find lots more information online about it.

Comment: @dsaxton So the first one is right?

Comment: Early on in derivation (2) somehow "$h+2$" disappeared from the denominator.  What was the justification for that?

Comment: @whuber Stolz–Cesàro theorem?

Comment: Since $B_{h+1}-B_{h}$ is a sequence of zeros and ones, it cannot converge unless it is eventually all zeros or all ones.  Those events have probability zero. The *general* form of Stolz–Cesàro certainly applies but only shows that the limit lies between $0$ and $1$ a.s.

Comment: @whuber I just rechecked Wiki. Do you mean $$0 = \liminf \frac{B_{h+1} - B_h}{1} \le \lim \frac{B_h + 1}{h+2} \le \limsup \frac{B_{h+1} - B_h}{1} = 1$$
?

Comment: @whuber 'it cannot converge unless it is eventually all zeros or all ones.' so #1 answer (the $Unif(0,1)$, not necessarily the solution) is correct?

Comment: I believe @dsaxton already indicated a good way to think about this problem.  Why don't you graph the (cumulative) distribution functions for some of the $P_h$?  It will be instantly obvious (1) that there is only one distribution to which they can possibly converge and (2) what it is.

Comment: @whuber Right. I guess it makes sense intuitively without graphing. But what about the details like lim E = E lim?

Comment: Those details perhaps ought to constitute separate questions.  @dsaxton has pointed out that you don't need any machinery to finish this problem: an elementary proof based on first principles is suggested by the graphs.

Comment: @whuber I mean it's one thing to explain something intuitively and another to give a proof right?